# jq command line, combine array of objects, do I need reduce? Or map? Or

Tags: json, stream, jq, data-munging

I have some JSON that looks like this.

```
{ "id": "tjh",
"records": [
  {  "name": "number_of_logins",
     "shortname": "nol",
     "value": 3 
   },
   {  "name": "failed_attempts",
      "shortname": "fa",
      "value": 4 
   },
   {  "name": "locations",
      "shortname": "loc",
      "value": 5 
   }
]}
```

It is in lines format with thousands of records in the file. Keep this in mind as an answer that might work for a single record, needs to work for the whole file.

I need to transform it to

```
ID , name:value,name:value,name:value
ID , name:value,name:value,name:value
ID , name:value,name:value,name:value
```

One line per json entry in the file.

So basically one line of output per id, or per id record in the file.

I am struggling with the following.

It seems I can reformat to get ID,list of values. 
I can also reformat to get ID,list of name.

When I add both I get duplicates.

Here it is on jqplay, https://jqplay.org/s/QTk42jn-a0

For example:

This is close:

```
.id , (.records[].name + ":")
```

It Returns,

```
"tjh"
"number_of_logins:"
"failed_attempts:"
"locations:"
```

This is REALLY close, I just need to add the value.

This is what happens when I go to add the value:

Filter:

```
.id , (.records[].name + ":" + (.records[].value|tostring))
```

Output:

```
"tjh"
"number_of_logins:3"
"failed_attempts:3"
"locations:3"
"number_of_logins:4"
"failed_attempts:4"
"locations:4"
"number_of_logins:5"
"failed_attempts:5"
"locations:5"
```

It is like I am triggering a full outer join somehow.

I suspect I might need reduce, or map.

Any advice is welcome, the interactive website url for testing jq, with my snippet is here.

https://jqplay.org/s/QTk42jn-a0

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your problem, but this might get you started.

```
jq -nr 'inputs
        | [ .id, ( .records[] | .name + ":" + (.value | tostring) ) ]
        | join (",")'
```

If you want ID space comma space at the start of the line, you could do this.

```
jq -nr 'inputs
        | .id + " , " + 
        ( [ .records[] | .name + ":" + (.value | tostring)  ] | join (",") )'
```

I believe the [manual entry](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) under "Array/Object Value Iterator: .[]" explains why you are getting the results you see.

Good luck!

Comment: This works, thank you for pointing to the docs to show why I was cross joining my arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation with `map`:

```
.id + " , " + (.records | map("\(.name):\(.value)") | join(","))
```

or even interpolation-within-interpolation:

```
"\(.id) , \(.records | map("\(.name):\(.value)") | join(","))"
```

Comment: I am having trouble running this on the command line, the first one returns a compile error, I assume some escaping is missing. I can't see it though. The second one works, thank you

Comment: In the first one, a backslash went missing. Fixed.